# reciprocal spherical harmonic expansion

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $f$ be a spherical function in $L^2(S^2)$ with spherical harmonic expansion $$f = \sum_{lm} f_{lm} \, Y_{lm} \;.$$
The function $g = 1/f$ is a spherical function. Assuming $g \in L^2(S^2)$, what is the spherical harmonic expansion of $g$ in terms of $f_{lm}$?

If no reference can be unearthed, perhaps someone can obtain the result from the following. The expansion of $fg$ is given by the Wigner $3j$-symbols,
$$
(fg)_{LM}
= \sum_{\substack{lm\\l'm'}} f_{lm} \, g_{l'm'} \, (-1)^{M} \, \sqrt{\tfrac{(2l+1)(2l'+1)(2L+1)}{4\pi}} \left(\begin{smallmatrix}l&l'&L\\m&m'&-M\end{smallmatrix}\right) \left(\begin{smallmatrix}l&l'&L\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right) \;.
$$
For $g = 1/f$ we have $fg = 1 = \sqrt{4\pi}\, Y_{00}$ and hence
$$
\sum_{\substack{lm\\l'm'}} f_{lm} \, g_{l'm'} \, \sqrt{(2l+1)(2l'+1)} \left(\begin{smallmatrix}l&l'&L\\m&m'&-M\end{smallmatrix}\right) \left(\begin{smallmatrix}l&l'&L\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)
= 4\pi \, \delta_{L0} \, \delta_{M0} \;.
$$
Can the sum be inverted?

Comment: Do we know the 1-D counterpart? I mean: what is the relation between the Fourier series coefficients of $f$ and $1/f$?

Comment: I think the 1D case is harder! We have $(fg)_N = \sum_{n} f_n g_{N-n}$, so that for $g=1/f$ we need to solve $\sum_{n} f_n \, g_{N-n} = \delta_{N0}$, i.e. much less to work with.